# Laravel: How to set my custom password broker to be used by Password::sendResetLink?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/passwords#requesting-the-password-reset-link) of Laravel says:

> You may be wondering how Laravel knows how to retrieve the user record from your application's database when calling the Password facade's sendResetLink method. The Laravel password broker utilizes your authentication system's "user providers" to retrieve database records. The user provider used by the password broker is configured within the passwords configuration array of your config/auth.php configuration file. To learn more about writing custom user providers, consult the authentication documentation

But how to set my custom password broker `users:foo` to be used by `Password::sendResetLink` in my custom package `packages/custom-packages/foo/src/routes/api.php`?

```
Route::post('forgot-password', function (Request $request) {
    $request->validate(['email' => 'required|email|exists:foo.users,email']);
    $status = Password::sendResetLink(
        $request->only('email')
    );
    return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
        ? response()->json(['status' => __($status)])
        : response()->json(['email' => __($status)]);
});
```

Below is my `config/auth.php`:

```
...
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
    'users:foo' => [
        'provider' => 'users:foo',
        'table' => 'foo.password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sets your broker through the facade.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;

$broker = 'users:foo'; // the default value is 'users' from 'auth.defaults.passwords'.

Password::broker($broker); // sets the given broker
```

It will get config from "auth.passwords.{$name}" where $name is $broker.

If the config of the broker is undefined then throws the exception: "Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.". In the good way will be created a new password broker with your config.